# mysql dump - character encoding

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, dump

I have a mysql dump  what contains ascii characters like `Ã¼berprÃ¼ft`. My problem is like I can not make another dump and I have been searching on the net for a solution but every suggestions would involve another dump set it up to utf-8. Is there a way to convert a dump file.

Answer (score 3):

Is the entire dump encoded like that, that is, in UTF-8? In that case you can simply set the encoding when you import the dump.

If you use the `mysql` command line client to import the dump, use the `--default-character-set` command line switch when importing, for example:

```
> mysql -u user --default-character-set=utf8 < dump.sql
```

Comment: yes it should be an utf-8 dump. I have been trying from command line and with sqlyog but without any success.